# Convertir correctamente un script con funciones a clases usando el patron factory

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un script hecho con puras funciones que necesito implementar programacion orientada a objetos y el patron de diseño factory , parte del script es este:

```
def create_auth_entity(label, address) -> AuthEntity:
    contact = Contact.objects.create(org_name=label, state="active", type="org")
    ContactAddress.objects.create(
        contact_id=contact.id,
        **address,
    )
    auth_entity = AuthEntity.objects.create(
        label=label, primary_contact_id=contact.id, state="active"
    )
    FinancialsClient.objects.create(auth_entity_id=auth_entity.id, label=label)
    return auth_entity


def create_contact(contact_details: dict) -> AuthEntity:
    contact = UserResource.create_contact(contact_details)
    auth_entity = UserResource.create_auth_entity(contact)
    contact.auth_entity_id = auth_entity.id
    contact.save()
    return auth_entity


def create_auth_credentials(auth_entity, email, secret):
    auth_credentials = AuthCredentials()
    auth_credentials.auth_entity = auth_entity
    auth_credentials.key = email
    auth_credentials.secret = secret
    auth_credentials.auth_method_name = "internal"
    auth_credentials.save()


def create_authenticated_service_subscription(
        auth_entity_id,
        owner_auth_entity_id,
        auth_entity_state,
        support=None,
):
    auth_service_published_id = get_service_published_id()
    service_subscription = ServiceSubscription.objects.create(
        owner_auth_entity_id=owner_auth_entity_id,
        auth_entity_id=auth_entity_id,
        service_published_id=auth_service_published_id,
        starts=dt.datetime.now(),
        state=auth_entity_state,
        support=support,
    )

    authenticated_subscription_group = ServiceSubscriptionGroup(
        service_subscription=service_subscription,
        service_group_name="authenticated",
        state=auth_entity_state,
    )
    authenticated_subscription_group.save(
        service_published_id=auth_service_published_id
    )

    return service_subscription


def create_service_subscriptions(
        auth_entity_id: int,
        owner_auth_entity_id: int,
        auth_entity_state: str,
        service_group_names: List[str],
):
    service_subscription = create_authenticated_service_subscription(
        auth_entity_id, owner_auth_entity_id, auth_entity_state, support=False
    )
    for service_group_name in service_group_names:
        ServiceSubscriptionGroup(
            service_subscription=service_subscription,
            service_group_name=service_group_name,
            state=auth_entity_state,
        ).save(service_published_id=get_service_published_id())


def create_msp_admin(msp: MSP):
    print("Creating MSP Admin")
    email = MSP_ADMIN_EASTRIDGE["email"]
    secret = MSP_ADMIN_EASTRIDGE_SECRET

    auth_entity = create_contact(MSP_ADMIN_EASTRIDGE)
    create_auth_credentials(auth_entity, email, secret)
    create_service_subscriptions(
        auth_entity.id, msp.auth_entity_id, "active", ["msp_admin", "msp_data_import"]
    )


def get_or_create_msp() -> MSP:
    print("Creating MSP")
    label = MSP_LABEL_EASTRIDGE
    address = PLACEHOLDER_ADDRESS

    msp = DBSession.query(MSP).filter(MSP.label == label).one_or_none()
    if msp:
        return msp

    auth_entity = create_auth_entity(label, address)
    msp = MSP(label=label, auth_entity_id=auth_entity.id)
    DBSession.add(msp)
    DBSession.flush()

    create_msp_admin(msp)
    return msp
```

lo que hice fue meter cada funcion en una clase + clase factory para llamar a esa clase, ejemplo:

```
class CreateContact:
    def __init__(self, contact_details):
        self.contact_details = contact_details

    def create_contact(self) -> AuthEntity:
        contact = UserResource.create_contact(self.contact_details)
        auth_entity = UserResource.create_auth_entity(contact)
        contact.auth_entity_id = auth_entity.id
        contact.save()
        return auth_entity


class CreateContactFactory:
    @staticmethod
    def create_object(some_property, contact_details):
        factory = {"create_contact": CreateContact}
        entity = factory.get(some_property)(contact_details)
        auth_entity = entity.create_contact()
        return auth_entity
```

por los ejemplos que he visto en internet se basa en situaciones como puede ser que unas clases compartan características por ejemplo la clase gato y clase perro que comparten raza, color y creo una clase factory en la que pueda elegir cualquiera de las 2 clases (gato o perro) pero en mi script que cada funcion es tan diferente de una a otra( y que cada una requiere diferentes parametros) no se me ocurre mas que crear un factory para cada clase pero no se que tan util sea al final usar este patron de diseño si es hacerlo asi, creo que posiblemente no lo este entendiendo bien , cualquier ayuda o consejo es apreciado.

Comment: Hay algunas cosas "raras" en tu versión puramente funcional, que no acabo de entender. De entrada, aunque tú has escrito funciones, éstas usan objetos y clases que no se sabe de dónde salen, como `Contact` o `ContactAddress`. Estas clases en sí mismas ya parecen ser factorías pues tienen cosas como `Conctact.object.create()`. Por otro lado, la segunda línea de `create_auth_entity()` invoca `ContactAddress.objects.create()` pero no recoge el resultado que esta función pueda devolver, así que ¿cuál es su objetivo? Lo mismo pasa poco después con `FinancialsClient.objects.create()`.

Comment: oh me falto mencionar eso, estas funciones utilizan por ejemplo `Contact` como algo externo y sobre `ContactAddress.objects.create()` igual es parte de otro script externo que se ocupa para la creacion del contacto, todo ese codigo es necesario para la correcta creacion de un contacto pero mas bien mi pregunta @abulafia no es tanto al funcionamiento sino al como poder aplicar factory + utilizando programacion orientada a objetos en mis funciones

Comment: Es que todo depende de qué haga exactamente la aplicación, cosa que no queda clara mirando el código que has puesto (que parece bastante complejo). La OOP se usa cuando tienes varias funciones que comparten un "estado" (variables globales, o bien muchos parámetros iguales que hay que pasar a todas ellas). Entonces el objeto podría guardar en sus atributos ese estado y así los métodos no necesitan tanto parámetro. O cuando puedes aprovechar código de una clase para otra mediante la herencia.

Comment: El patrón factory se usaría para crear una clase capaz de crear objetos de otras clases, si quieres por ejemplo controlar cosas como  cuántos objetos se han creado, o ciertos parámetros que necesites usar en la creación de objetos de distinto tipo...

Comment: Es difícil responder la pregunta sin entender el contexto. No conocemos a fondo tu aplicación ni se trata de que nos pongamos a estudiarla. Quizás deberías hacer un esfuerzo por describir qué hace desde más alto nivel, en vez de dar todo el código que de todas formas no se entiende por depender de clases externas.